# Put one grid bigger without chaging the size of other grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have two grids of same size but I want put one of them bigger and when I change the size of the Row the other grid gets smaller. Im maybe not understading who grids works but the last Row with Height="*" should scale according my rows.

I tried this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And looks like this if you compare with the other image you will see the firsts two buttons have changed the sizes, and I only want the seconds.

[image: With different size]

Normal code.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.02*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.001*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.001*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" RowSpacing="0" x:Name="MiddleGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*" x:Name="Price"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="melaopresunto.png" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CategoryImage"/>
                        <Label Text="Melão c/ Presunto" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <Label Text="6.90€" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False" x:Name="Quantity" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="#800E152F">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Text="-" TextColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="#3F3C42" Clicked="QntLabelLess" x:Name="QntLess" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="QntLabel" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Button Text="+" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="#FF8A00" Clicked="QntLabelPlus" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="QntPlus"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.03*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ImageButton Source="sobremesa.png" BackgroundColor="Black" Clicked="Ingredients" x:Name="Ingredient" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                        </ImageButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame>


            <Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.02*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.001*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.001*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="1" RowSpacing="0" x:Name="MiddleGrid1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*" x:Name="Price1"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="melaopresunto.png" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CategoryImage1"/>
                        <Label Text="Melão c/ Presunto" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <Label Text="6.90€" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False" x:Name="Quantity1" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="#800E152F">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.05*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Text="-" TextColor="White" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="False" BackgroundColor="#3F3C42" Clicked="QntLabelLess1" x:Name="QntLess1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="QntLabel1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Button Text="+" Padding="0" CornerRadius="4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="#FF8A00" Clicked="QntLabelPlus1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="QntPlus1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped1"
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame>


            <Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2.8*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="carne.png" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Pomedoro" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Label Text="3,50€" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>


            <Frame BackgroundColor="#40000000" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="6" Padding="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2.8*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="carne.png" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Salada de Legumes" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Label Text="5,50€" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
</Grid>
```

[image: With same size]

I know it's a lot of code but you don't really need to know what is inside the frames.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Change the size of second row to 1.2* without chaging the size of first row. Looks like you are Portuguese so if you want talk in a chat would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

> And looks like this if you compare with the other image you will see the firsts two buttons have changed the sizes, and I only want the seconds.

According to your description, you want to change grid second row Row Definition height, and other row definition height don't change size, and last row definition should scale, am I right?

If yes, please take a look * and Auto for Grid definition.

1.Star (“*”), this means that the column will take the whole available space.

2. Auto, column/row will adapt to the child  element size.

For example, there are three row and two column in grid, if you want to change second row definition height, but the first row definition height don't change, you can do this， set the size for first row definition child element.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1.2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label HeightRequest="150"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="Black" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="Brown" />
        <Label
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="this is test!" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" />
    </Grid>
```